# How to inject ServiceManager into a user defined class

Tags: zend-framework2, inject, service-locator

In the doc it's said:"By default, the Zend Framework MVC registers an initializer that will inject the ServiceManager instance, which is an implementation of Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface, into any class implementing Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface."

so I tried this:

```
interface ModelResourceInterface extends ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
}

interface ServiceModelResourceInterface extends ModelResourceInterface
{
    public function fetch($uri, $method, $parameters, $options, $encodeType);
}


namespace Ssports\Model\Resource\Service\Http;

use Ssports\Model\Resource\Service\ServiceModelResourceInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Ssports\Model\Resource\Service\ConnectionException;

abstract class AbstractHttpServiceModelResource implements ServiceModelResourceInterface
{

    /**
     *
     * @var Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
     */
    protected $serviceLocator;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->init();
    }

    /**
     * Extend Constructor
     */
    public function init()
    {}

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     *
     * @see \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface::setServiceLocator()
     *
     */
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     *
     * @see \Ssports\Model\Resource\Service\ServiceModelResourceInterface::fetch()
     *
     */
    public function fetch($uri, $method, $parameters = null, $options = null, $encodeType = null)
    {
        try {
                //something raise \RuntimeException
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Log\Web');
            throw new ConnectionException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     *
     * @see \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface::getServiceLocator()
     *
     */
    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
}
```

I extend this abstract class with some model resource class, and run it, and an exception throw to say that I'm calling get on a non-object.

Seem that the service manager is not being injected to my abstract class, and the return of getServiceLocator is NULL.

Any thing I missed to make it right?

Comment: It's better to only inject the classes that you need instead of the full registry of classes. Right now all i see is a "logger" - inject that logger, not the ServiceManager!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the service locator trait?

It can be found in \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait

However this requires PHP 5.4 to work...

To use a trait do the following

```
class Class1
{
  use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;
}
```

You can access the service locator then, or at least that is how i had to do it when i needed to load the service locator.

Comment: I found what's wrong here. because the abtract class can't be inialized, so you can just write the set and get method for extension by other child class, but you can't invoke the serviceLocator in it since it won't be instanced.

Comment: ah ok np, at least you got it sorted!